# Data storage on Corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am working on a use case. The requirement being I need to create an order. The order has some customer parameters. The order can be modified multiple times. Initially, I thought of implementing it in Ethereum. So, I thought of capturing the customer details from a UI and store it on the smart contract. However, the issue is once the contract is deployed I cannot change it since it is immutable. This drawback prevents me to use Ethereum. Deliberating on Corda, can I store the customer data as a single records and make modifications to it such that modifications are stored on the ledger which we can query. For instance, I want to store customer ID, Customer name, customer purchase order number, order type, and order status.

How would I do that in Corda data model?
Will that data be modifiable based on the rules coded on smart contract?
The data can be queried?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

In Corda, you store information using `State`s. In your case, you might create a `CustomerDataState` class. You'd then create instances of this class on the ledger to represent your various customers.

This data can then be updated using *transactions*. But not all transactions are allowed. Which transactions are valid is based on the rules in the associated `CustomerDataContract`. The `CustomerDataContract` will be stateless, and simply exists to say how `CustomerDataState`s can evolve over time.

You can then easily query this data from your node's vault or transaction storage using an SQL-style syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert. Answered most of my doubts. If I get a customer order and in future get a modification request on the same order. How to handle that. For instance, I get a request from a customer A. The system creates order id: 12345. Now customer A wants to modify the order, he cannot do that since in corda either the state is consumed or created. We cannot modify it.

Comment: You'd propose a transaction that consumes the existing state and issues a new state that represents the new version of the order. For example, you'd consume the Order12345 with a value of 10, and create a new Order with id 12345 but value 15.

Comment: Didn't get you. What is the significance of value 10 and 15 here?

Comment: Oh, it was just an example for if you wanted to change the value of the order. Basically, you create a transaction consuming the OrderState with the old attributes, and issuing an OrderState with the new attributes.

Comment: So, in this case the order 12345 value 10 gets consumed by a trasaction Tx1 and output state is order 12345 with value 15. Then in terms of audit ability if I want to audit the order, will I get details of order 12345 with value 10? As it has been already consumed

Comment: Yes - it will be in your vault and transaction storage still. You'll want your `OrderState` to subclass `LinearState`. Then each `OrderState` that corresponds to the same order over time should share the same `linearId`.

Comment: Is there any reference document to study data models that can be created on Corda.

Comment: Check out https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts.html and then https://docs.corda.net/api-index.html.